# Shared folder over azure VM

Tags: azure, file, azure-active-directory, shared

I tried to create a shared folder on azure VM via azure AD. I created a local machine and joined the domain and connected to vpn. I can ping machines with private IPs but I can not connect to the shared folder in any way.

[Azure VM ipconfig and arp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS6ck.png)

[local VM ipconfig and arp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt5oy.png)

[Azure VM shared folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXSRE.png)

[local VM shared folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyjCw.png)

[Azure VM ping local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFiLh.png)

[local machine ping Azure VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEScW.png)

**Azure Virtual network (newADD2-vnet):**

Address space 10.3.0.0/16

Subnets: DomainService 10.3.0.0/24, GatewaySubnet 10.3.1.0/24

**Virtual network gateway(VNet1GW):**

Point-to-site configuration: 10.50.0.0/24
Configured Root certificates

What could have gone wrong? What else can I check what may not work?

Thanks for your help
DKU

Answer (score 1):

**Ensure port 445 is open**: The SMB protocol requires TCP port 445 to be open; connections will fail if port 445 is blocked.  You will need to ensure it's open on the VM firewall and open in the [Network Security Group for the VM in Azure](http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/microsoft-azure/create-new-nsg-network-security-group-virtual-firewall-acl-on-microsoft-azure).

Comment: I opened 139,445 (TCP) 138 and 137(UDP).

Answer (score 1):

Add to the existing answer, except for firewall in Azure VM and NSG, you could check if the outbound rule for port 445 is blocking on the local machine. Also, avoid some typo when you input the UNC path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ports 139,445 (TCP) 138 and 137(UDP). Also, add an exclusion for the **Windows defender**.